# Supply some basic auth credentials to a WebView?

Tags: android

I have a WebView. I'd like to show some page from my server, but I require some basic authentication. Is there a way I can specify basic auth credentials when calling WebView.loadData() somehow? I can do this on iphone with the equivalent webview class, thinking maybe same is possible with android?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call:

```
 setHttpAuthUsernamePassword (String host, String realm, String username, String password)
```

read more [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setHttpAuthUsernamePassword)

Comment: Cool that's pefect, thanks! If my url is like http://mysite.com/test, what would 'host' and 'realm' be? Host should be = 'mysite.com' ? Thanks

Comment: host should be the protected directory. The Realm information is an arbitrary string sent to be displayed to the user commonly containing a sight message, or feedback. Anyway is not used in this scenario.

Comment: also look into this http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg30468.html