# How to handle Basic Authentication in WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

I've created an application which loads a WebView. In order to login,
the website requires basic authentication. When i try to access the website
via the default browser, I get a pop up box prompting me to enter my user name
and password.

If I try to access the website via my application, I get error 401 and no pop up.
I was wondering if someone could help me out?

Answer (score 41):

I reckon a more elegant solution than the one Patrick describes would be to use the `onReceivedHttpAuthRequest` method of WebViewClient as described here: http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg30468.html

```
@Override
public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view, HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {
    handler.proceed("username", "password");
}
```

Comment: Does not work anymore like this, the method does not seem to exist anymore.

Comment: For the code above you must remove super. onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(). otherwise It will call handle.cancel that would make your code won't work .

Answer (score 13):

The website requires authentication.

First you react to the error:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
   public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
     if (errorCode == 401) {
         // show alert to enter username and password
         // then when those are entered in the alert,
         //     set it through the setHttpAuthUsernamePassword(...) shown below
         //     and then reload the site
     }
   }
 });
```

Use this function to set user and password: [`WebView.setHttpAuthUsernamePassword()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setHttpAuthUsernamePassword(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

```
webview.setHttpAuthUsernamePassword(host, realm, username, password);
```

All are strings. See the link above for more information on what host and realm means.

Solution found here: [Supply some basic auth credentials to a WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580984/supply-some-basic-auth-credentials-to-a-webview)

Comment: Thanks guys for the quick response. Correct me if i'm wrong, But wont webview.setHttpAuthUsernamePassword(host, realm, username, password);
require that I predefine the username and password within the code? I was trying to figure out how to have the app pop up a username/login box like the default browser does..

Comment: ok.. will add to explain how to do that in my post here.. just a second.

Comment: Thanks again! I'm still receiving the 401, but I'm going to keep trying at this to try and get it working.

Answer (score 11):

```
public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view, HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {
     handler.proceed("USERNAME", "PASSWORD");
}
```

I think it helpful about the 401 error on WebView.

Comment: I have tried this method and it ended up in a mess. I highly discourage using this method. If you supply a wrong user name or password the authentication fails and webview keeps on retrying for auth. This was creating repeated api calls on my server which ended up server getting down. You may consider using a counter and stopLoading() method to avoid infinite looping.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but adding another approach here as the ones above (using the onReceivedHttpAuthRequest) didn't work for me. Specifically some web pages don't prompt the user for Basic Authentication, they just redirect to the login screen. In my testing, Grafana happens to have this behavior by default.

So instead I added a HTTP Basic auth header using the below code:

```
HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
String basicAuthHeader = android.util.Base64.encodeToString((username + ":" + password).getBytes(), android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP);
headers.put("Authorization", "Basic " + basicAuthHeader);
webView.loadUrl(url, headers);
```

This should bypass the auth prompt and just set the credentials automatically. Hope this helps someone looking for another solution.

Also, for anyone hoping to use the URL pattern of "https://username:password@url" - this is deprecated and I think most browsers will ignore it and throw away the credentials.

**edit**

I've come to the realization my above solution only works for the first request, and no subsequent requests after the page is loaded (i.e. for any further resources loaded).

In order for all subsequent requests to work, I had to override the following function for the web client:

```
@Override
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request){
    if (username != null && password != null && username.length() > 0 && password.length() > 0) {
        try {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Request.Builder newRequestBuilder = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(request.getUrl().toString());

            // add headers
            Map<String, String> currentHeaders = request.getRequestHeaders();
            for (String header : currentHeaders.keySet()){
                newRequestBuilder.addHeader(header, currentHeaders.get(header));
            }
            String basicAuthHeader = android.util.Base64.encodeToString((username + ":" + password).getBytes(), android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP);
            newRequestBuilder.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+basicAuthHeader);

            //make request
            Request newRequest = newRequestBuilder.build();
            Response response = client.newCall(newRequest).execute();

            // respond with content
            return new WebResourceResponse(response.header("content-type"), response.header("content-encoding", "utf-8"), response.body().byteStream());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // if an exception occurs, just make a default request
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        // if no username and password, then make a default request
        return null;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this code will not intercept POST requests, only GET requests, which limits what you can do with it.

Further, the above code should have some logic added to verify the domain of the initial request matches the domain of the intercepted requests before attaching the Authorization headers. Otherwise the Authorization header will be sent with all requests which could unintentionally send it to a different domain (e.g. loading resources from a CDN).

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me add username/pass WebViewClient then setWebViewClient

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient ());

//add this class in main activity 
class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view,
                                          HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {

        handler.proceed("your username", "your password");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function **onReceivedHttpAuthRequest**. It Notifies the host application that the WebView received an HTTP authentication request. The host application can use the supplied **HttpAuthHandler** to set the WebView's response to the request. The default behavior is to cancel the request.

Below is the sample written in **Kotlin**

```
 override fun onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(
            view: WebView,
            handler: HttpAuthHandler,
            host: String,
            realm: String
        ) {
            handler.proceed("username", "password")
        }
```

[Check the Documentation here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.HttpAuthHandler,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))