# Asp.net and android webview problem

Tags: asp.net, android, iis

My IIS server requires authentication to access the localserver

this is causing android WebView component to get 403 error once directed the the url

if I uncheck Basic Authentication under Directory found in

Computer Management -> Web Sites -> Properties

I would receive 403 error(Access Denied) this time including my browser

once I restart my computer

How do I disable authentication without losing access to it?

if this is not possible

Is there a way to allow android WebView enter the username and password

automatically to prevent 403 error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WebView Basic Authentication help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220832/webview-basic-authentication-help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle Basic Auth in WebView: [How to handle Basic Authentication in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220832/webview-basic-authentication-help)

Comment: Still not working, I tried webview.setHttpAuthUsernamePassword("10.0.2.2", "", username, password); but it I'm still experiencing 403 error. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: Try using domain name as set in your IIS config. If it is not set than it's the default domain of your IIS. Also check "realm". http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/f85f0f16-4fea-4852-980c-4982d53c9948.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: I did it again, still not working webview.setHttpAuthUsernamePassword("10.0.2.2", "subdomain.site.com", username, password);

Comment: package com.android.browserweb;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
public class ActBrowser extends Activity {
WebView browser;
@Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

                

        browser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webkit);

        browser.setHttpAuthUsernamePassword("10.0.2.2","the.realm.com","myusername", "mypassword");                

        browser.loadUrl("http://10.0.2.2/pathtodir");                    

    }

}