# Android Webview javascript popups

Tags: javascript, c#, android, webview, xamarin

I have a webpage that asks for a username and password when someone connects to it. I made a simple app in C# Xamarin. It just has a webview in it. My aplication's purpose is that I can just open the aplication and see my webcam and I don't need to enter all the passwords everytime I want to see my webcam.

But my problem is that when I try to navigate to the webpage this pops up in my webview:
[image: webview]

When I go to the same page on my phone this pops up:
[image: Webpage on my phone]
So is there a way to show this popup on my webview and/or automaticly fill these and click the login button?

What I have tried:

```
WV.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
WV.Settings.JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true;
```

Comment: this is what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220832/webview-basic-authentication-help Regards,
Vladimir

Comment: and WV.SetWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); didn't wortk either

Comment: setHttpAuthUsernamePassword (String host, String realm, String username, String password) still gives me a 401 error...

Comment: Did you try with public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view, HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {
     handler.proceed("USERNAME", "PASSWORD");
}