# Android Studio access webcam via WebView

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, webcam

I'm trying to access and display a webcam interface in my application.
Currently I'm trying to do that using a WebView (still no success), but open to other suggestions.

When I go to "http://192.168.43.74:81" (the ip of the camera) on my phone's browser I get a popup asking me to insert a username and a password, I do that and log the camera successfully.
This is how I try to do that using a WebView:

```
    WebView camera = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.camera);
    camera.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    camera.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    camera.loadUrl(CAMERA_URL);
    camera.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

When I set CAMERA_URL to google's url for example, I'm able to access google and browse the internet normally, using the webview. When I set CAMERA_URL to the webcam's IP, I get a blank page on my webview, and the following message:

> **Access Error: Unauthorized**
>   Access to this document requires a User ID

This is the same message I get when I try to log in via my browser, but hit cancel instead of trying to log in. I assume I'm doing something wrong, and would appreciate some help:

- How do I make it work?
- Is there a better way to go about it than a WebView?
- and finally, though a somewhat different question, is there a way to automatically make the login instead of having the user type the username/password every time?

I apologize if this question is trivial, or has been asked before. I was unable to find a solution by searching. Thank you!

Comment: You need to implement basic authentication.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220832/how-to-handle-basic-authentication-in-webview

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works great. For some reason I can't upvote/accept your answer. I have another question. When I load the page from the webcam, only a part of the page is displayed and I can't reach the rest of it even using scrolling  or pinch zooming. It's as if that part is the whole page. Heres how it looks like (the webview is supposed to cover only half the screen, so thats ok): http://i.imgur.com/muOHSrh.jpg